# What does chrome.storage.onChanged track?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does `chrome.storage.onChanged` track storage item changes both locally and in the cloud?

The one-liner description in the documentation is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For synchronized storage (`chrome.storage.sync`), `onChanged` is triggered for both local and remote changes.

This feature has been acknowledged by a member of the Chromium Extensions team in [http://crbug.com/361113#c4](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361113#c4). Though unlike the standard [`window.onstorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event) event (*only* for DOM storage changes), the `chrome.storage.onChanged` event is *also* triggered in the execution environment that triggered the storage change. This was [considered to be a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361113#c4), so the behavior might change in the future such that `chrome.storage.onChanged` is *only* triggered for changes initiated in other (local/remote) documents, not for changes from the same document.

Comment: One needs to be **very careful** with that statement. The dev meant that firing `onChange` if the same local _context_ committed the change is superfluous. If another page in the extension changes something, it's still "local" but `onChange` **must** fire.